# Geopandas way of removing child geometries

Tags: python, geometry, gis, geopandas, shapely

I have huge list shapely polygon objects, which has lots of possible geometries, which might fall between each other.

I am trying to find most efficient way of keeping only parent/containing shapes and need to get rid of any child shapes.

The ways, which I have tried are:

- Approach 1: Do n-square way of finding if any polygon is contrained in any other polygon, it is candidate for deleting from the list. But this is very bad performance given I have 6 million shapes.
- Approach 2: Create a spatial tree(KDE tree or ball tree) of all the polygon centers and then find maybe 5000 nearest polygon for each polygon's center and check if any of them fall in the center's polygon, if any mark it as child. Do this for all the polygons and later drop all the child polygons. This approach works, but it seems not clean to me and also, number 5000 is hard coded assuming no polygon have more than 5000 child polygons(which practically is the case). but I am not satisfied with this sub-par code.

Quations to all the GeoPandas people:

Q: There must be a better way drop children polygons by doing some sort of spatial join and finding all the child polygons easily. Please share some examples.

Comment: Have you tried using geopandas.sjoin? It uses a tree and is pretty efficient. Certainly faster than anything you could implement in pure python or shapely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have pygeos in your environment and everything up to date, you can use spatial index with `contains_properly` predicate to filter geometries fully within other geometries. See the toy example:

```py
import numpy
import geopandas
import pandas

pts = geopandas.GeoSeries.from_xy(x=numpy.random.randint(0, 100, 50), y=numpy.random.randint(0, 100, 50))
# create polygons that are one within the other
geoms = pd.concat([pts.buffer(1), pts.buffer(2)])

parent_idx, children_idx = geoms.sindex.query_bulk(geoms, predicate="contains_properly")
```

The result gives you integer indices for all parents and all children. Geometries that are not parent/children are not returned.